# Can you use a name like "HELLOWorld.class" for a java program?

Tags: java

I could not execute my java program by a command line, although the Eclipse's "Run" menu executed it. While examining the problem, I happened to find that changing the name from `HELLOWorld` to `HelloWorld` fixed the problem for my particular case. Does really Java's naming rule restrict such names?

Comment: If its a public class, then its name must match with the filename of the file it is declared in....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Java Language Specification states the requirements for a class name](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/lexical.html#3.8) (which is an *Identifier*). To sum it up: it must begin with a letter or underscore, and the remainder may contain letters or digits.

Thus, `HELLOWorld` *is* a valid classname, however, if your class is `public`, the filename and classname **must** match (you will receive a compilation error otherwise).

Comment: Your answer implies my problem is not by the class name. Because you say that the compilation fails in such conditions.

Answer (score 3):

Your file name must match to the public class name that you defined in that file. May be this might be the case in your scenario.

Comment: Yes. that is what I meant. (I am from non-english speaking country :P)

Answer (score 0):

in one word, `Yes`

public class name must be same as class file name

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The name of your public class must be same as the name of your filename i.e .java file.However you may have number of other classes also.